# Array to CheckboxList and again to array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, checkedlistbox

Hi everyone i have a little problem. 
I get the items from this array

```
this.HeaderFields = new string[]{ "PROJ_ID", "MODEL", "ESN", "LOCATION", "DATATYPE", "TESTTYPE", "TEST", "TRRDG", "RDG", "TESTDATE", "TESTTIME" };
```

and set them into a `CheckedListBox` with this line of code

```
checkedlstBoxHeaderField.Items.AddRange(settings.HeaderFields);
Controls.Add(checkedlstBoxHeaderField);
```

That works. When i open my winforms i want to check some of the values and than with OK Button to go nextStep and then when i reopen the form i want to see all items checked and unchecked. I try so

```
settings.HeaderFields = checkedlstBoxHeaderField.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

but with these line of code i became just the checked items. Please help....

Answer (score 2):

```
settings.HeaderFields = checkedlstBoxHeaderField.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Then save this string array somewhere before closing this page

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide and show the form to persist your selections,
OR

//save your data to file

```
//Whole List
settings.HeaderFields = checkedlstBoxHeaderField.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\TestFolder\AllData.txt", HeaderFields );

//Selected List
settings.HeaderFields = checkedlstBoxHeaderField.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\TestFolder\SelectedData.txt", HeaderFields );



//Read Them back from files

settings.HeaderFields  = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TestFolder\AllData.txt");
checkedlstBoxHeaderField.Items.AddRange(settings.HeaderFields);
Controls.Add(checkedlstBoxHeaderField);

settings.HeaderFields  = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TestFolder\SelectedData.txt");
//now loop through the Checkbox list add select the accoring to the data from SelectedData.txt


System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\TestFolder\SelectedData.txt");
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\TestFolder\AllData.txt");
```

Or you can save them to datatables